# Whats the best way to account for every possibility for two booleans

Tags: if-statement, boolean, logic, boolean-logic

So I have run into this a few times now and was wondering if there is some kind of smart way to do it? I mostly program in C#, C++ and JavaScript so a cool method in any of those languages would be helpful. I'm primarily looking for speed, but if there are other things I should be cognisent of I'd love to know about them.
I'll show you an example of what I write generally:

```
if(bool0 || bool1)
{
   if(!bool0)
   {
      if(!bool1)
      {
         // do stuff
      }
      else
      {
         // do stuff
      }
   }
   else
   {
      if(!bool1)
      {
         // do stuff
      }
      else
      {
         // do stuff
      }
   }
}
```

The other thing I'm wondering is, could this be done in a switch statement? Probably not best practice but I thought it was an interesting idea.

Comment: Switch statements are highly language (and sometimes platform) dependent.  The C# switch statement does *not* work like the C/C++ switch.

Comment: I was thinking you'd use binary operators and cast it to an int.

Answer (score 1):

You have 4 cases:

```
if(bool0 && bool1)
else if(!bool0 && bool1)
else if(bool0 && !bool1)
else if(!bool0 && !bool1)
```